# Should I get data from APi or should I just pass it through actions?

Tags: reactjs, rest, redux

I have some data (like month ID) in frontend (React) that is used to create URL and send via POST method. It sends some info to the server and then server returns appropriate response.

I am using Redux. So in my reducer when I get the response from API I need that month ID to update state.

My question is: Is it better to send month ID as a field in the response from the API or is it better to send month ID through action argument?

Comment: Your reducer shouldn't handle async functions. The way I do it, is my action returns a promise that a middleware catches, solves, and sends to redux only the answer of the api call

Comment: Ofcourse, my reducer isn't having any async calls. It gets data and works with it. I am asking which way should one field of that data (month ID) be provided.

Answer (score 0):

What are you using to handle async actions, redux thunk? redux saga?

Generally it's best to update the store on a successful response, as you can be more sure your new state is valid. It's also common to 'eager' update the store before the response has returned, and then revert that change if the response fails.

Comment: I am using redux thunk. I just want to know which source of information is better. From the API or from the form itself.